# jQuery: unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, expression

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var page = window.location.hash;
    if(page != ""){
        $('a[href='+ page +']').addclass('selected');
        pageload(page.replace('#/page/', 'pages/?load='));
    }

    $('#top a').click(function(event){  
        $('#top a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        pageload($(this).attr('href').replace('#/page/', 'pages/?load='));

        event.preventDefault;
    });
});
```

```
<div id="top">
    <a href="#/page/link">Link</a>
    <a href="#/page/link">Link</a>
    <a href="#/page/link">Link</a>
    <a href="#/page/link">Link</a>
    <a href="#/page/link">Link</a>
</div>
```

So when i'm trying to do this, and load up a page using the `window.location.hash`, i get an error in the console saying:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [href=#/page/link]

How can i make this work?

Comment: Are you aware that you are not actually calling `event.preventDefault` function? You should do that as the first thing in your event handler.

Comment: Well print out the $(this).attr('href') part into console.log

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('a[href="'+ page +'"]').addClass('selected');
```

(You need to escape the value of the `href` – with this, you get `a[href="#/page/link"]`.)

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addclass'"

this is what i get in return.

Comment: Ah, the C in addClass needed to be capital, stupid me. Thanks!

Comment: good call - starting from jQ 1.5 url needs to be wrapped into something, e.g. href="my/url/" -- href=my/url/ will not go through anymore

Comment: $(container+":has(ul)").length how to change that?

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano: What do you mean?

Comment: i have the line if ($(container+":has(ul)").length === 0){...} in jquery 1.3.2, then got error when i upgrade the jquery to 1.8.2. How to upgrade my code too? the error is "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]:has(ul)"

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't need the speech marks:

```
replace(#/page/, ...
```